# Zip a directory excluding files/folder that do not belong to the current user

Tags: zip

I would like to zip a directory but only include files and folders that belong to the current user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from the command line by using `find` to select the files belonging to the current user, and feeding the result to the `zip` command using the `-@` option. Something along the lines of:

```
find /directory/to/zip -type f -user $USER -print | zip -@ result.zip
```

(untested)